# which searching technique is implemented when we search a file using fopen() in c

Tags: c++, c, file, search

I'm dealing with very large number of text files (about 10^5 to 10^6 files). In every iteration I want to select a random number and be able to load associate text file's content to a buffer.

Now my question is what kind of search techniques used to locate the file?

Comment: That is completely dependent on the OS and filesystem your code runs on, and the filename search strategies vary wildly. It would be the same regardless of the programming language you're using, nothing to do with C/C++.

Comment: It's not uncommon for an OS to deal poorly with individual directories containing tens of thousands of files or more.  A common and easily-implemented technique which helps a lot is to implement a hierarchical subdirectory structure.  For example, if your files have "names" like `504cba1b815bc171`, you might store that file in `50/4c/504cba1b815bc171`.

Comment: In general, though, putting one million files in a single directory is unlikely to end well. Consider another way to organize the files. If you share something about the file naming convention, someone may have some ideas for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments it is OS dependent. For what I know the C Standard does not even mention directories.

If you want an efficient search technique you have to implement it yourself. If you write a lot you can sort of implement it using the OS to do lookup through directory hierarchies with O(n*log(n)) average complexity.

If primarily read-only it'd be near as simple and a lot faster putting the files in a single file, treating it as a virtual file system and have your application search through it using whatever search algorithm you choose. The speed comes from fewer OS and filesystem calls. Writing becomes bit of a bigger issue since the `FILE*` don't do insertions very well in-place without major relocation or memory.